# navbar add new div yii2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

Code of base NavBar widget in Yii2, gives me structure of html like this

```
<nav id="w1" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">...</div>
        <div id="w1-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul>...</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But I need to get such a structure

```
<nav id="w1" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="side_item">...a lot of html with login and cart...</div>
        <div class="navbar-header">...</div>
        <div id="w1-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul>...</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I add div into standart NavBar template?

Comment: Have you tried extending that class and adding your own methods?

Comment: 2 optiond, I guess: overwriting methods or writing your own HTML.

Comment: Looks like I cant do this by standart options, so can u explain what method i should overwrite